# How to pick between two forms using python requests library?

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to use the requests library to submit a POST request to a website that contains two forms. The site is https://itsapps.unc.edu/dir/dirSearch/view.htm and I am trying to access the advanced search form.

The html of the forms looks like:

```
...
<div id="basicSearch" class="yui-hidden">
   <form onSubmit="return false;" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   ...
   </form>
</div>                                     
<div id="advancedSearch"><!-- advanced search -->
   <form onSubmit="return false;" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
       <table class="section">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label for="affiliation">Search
...
```

How would I go about doing this? Is there a way to specify the form id/name? Right now all I have is:

```
url = 'https://itsapps.unc.edu/dir/dirSearch/search'
form_data = {'affiliation':'students',
         'firstname':'Anthony'}

response = requests.post(url, data=form_data)
print response.text
```

Because the advanced search option has affiliation as a drop down, I assumed having it within the form parameter will automatically select the form that matches the params, but the output does not changes when I remove the affiliation parameter from form_data.

Note, the form data seen when checking developer tools network info for basic search is:

```
searchString=Anthony
```

and for advanced search is:

```
affiliation=student&firstname=Anthony&lastname=&email=&pid=&onyen=
```

Comment: You don't select a form. A browser would simply send everything that's part of the submitted form, the server will sort out the rest.

Comment: It could be that the server doesn't care what form is used; one form just contains different fields to send (perhaps just extra fields) but the POST handler on the server can handle either.

Comment: So that means I can just make sure advanced search is returned by just specifying the affiliation (which is not in the basic search)?

Comment: Perhaps; it depends on the exact implementation of the POST handler. I also haven't studied what the JS code does that is being called; it could be that that code adds extra fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to post to `https://itsapps.unc.edu/dir/dirSearch/search` and you will get some json returned:

```
In [1]: data = {
   ...:         "firstname": "Laurel",
   ...:         "lastname": "Foote-Hudson"}

In [2]: 

In [2]: r = requests.post("https://itsapps.unc.edu/dir/dirSearch/search", data=data)

In [3]: print(r.json())
[{u'uncReverseDisplayName': u'Foote-Hudson, Laurel', u'telephoneNumber': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'eduPersonNickname': u'Laurel', u'uncPreferredSurname': u'Foote-Hudson', u'sn': u'Foote-Hudson', u'spid': u'240a0d7c1534aa3a', u'mail': u'xxxxxxxxxxx', u'givenName': u'Laurel'}
```

You can see the post form fields using chrome or firefox:

[image]

The fields you don't supply are empty.

Comment: I'm running the program via eclipse. How did you find the network stuff on chrome? it doesn't pop up when I run the program within chrome's development tools window.

Comment: Open developer tools, select the network tab and submit, you will see the data under doc

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out using developer tools / firebug / other browser extensions. There's nothing that explicitly says which form you selected. The only difference is which fields are sent back to the server.

In case of the advanced search, keep in mind that all the fields are sent - even if they're empty.

Comment: Then how do I control which fields are sent back to the server? I dont want any information from the basic search.

Comment: Your `form_data` is what you send. Include the fields you want only.